# matplotlib heatmap, customize y axis

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

Right now my code looks like this:

```
#generate 262*20 elements
values = np.random.random(262*20).tolist()
# convert the list to a 2D NumPy array
values = np.array(values).reshape((262, 20))
h, w = values.shape
#h=262, w=20
fig = plt.figure(num=None, dpi=80,figsize=(9, 7), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')   
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(values)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(np.arange(w), list('PNIYLKCVFWABCDEFGHIJ'))
ax.set_aspect(w/h)
plt.show()
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the range of y axis is 0-261.

But I want my y axis to go from 26 to 290, missing 57, 239, and 253. So still 262 in total. I tried to generate a list like this:

```
mylist =[26, 27, ......missing 57, 239, 253, ....290]
plt.yticks(np.arange(h), mylist)
```

The Y axis just looks like everything squished together.

So I tried:

```
pylab.ylim([26, 290])
```

And It looks like this:

[image]

So it just feels like the data in first row always corresponds to [0], not to [26]

Comment: I think you need to modify the tick labels (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20xlabel#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel)) and not the ticks themselves. The ticks correspond to the actual data and unless you generate a data from the range 26-290, simply changing the ticks will not give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you use `pcolormesh`.  If you want gaps, then use an `numpy.ma.masked` array for the area with gaps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

values = np.random.rand(290,20)
values[:26, :] = np.NaN
values[ [57, 239, 253], :] = np.NaN
values = np.ma.masked_invalid(values)

h, w = values.shape
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,7))
# Make one larger so these values represent the edge of the data pixels.
y = np.arange(0, 290.5)
x = np.arange(0, 20.5)

pcm = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, values, rasterized=True) # you don't need rasterized=True
fig.colorbar(pcm)
plt.xticks(np.arange(w), list('PNIYLKCVFWABCDEFGHIJ'))
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eE3w.png)

EDIT:  If you want to just work w/ a 262x20 array:

```
values = np.random.rand(262,20)

h, w = values.shape
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,7))
# Make one larger so these values represent the edge of the data pixels.
y = np.arange(0, 290.5)
y = np.delete(y, [57, 239, 253])
y = np.delete(y, range(26))

x = np.arange(0, 20.5)

pcm = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, values, rasterized=True) # you don't need rasterized=True
fig.colorbar(pcm)
plt.xticks(np.arange(w), list('PNIYLKCVFWABCDEFGHIJ'))

plt.show()
```

Note that this doesn't put a blank line at 57, 239 and 253.  If you want that, you need to do:

```
values = np.random.rand(262,20)
Z = np.ones((290, 20)) * np.NaN
inds = set(range(290)) - set(list(range(26)) + [57, 239, 253])
for nn, ind in enumerate(inds):
    Z[ind, :] = values[nn,:]

h, w = values.shape
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,7))
# Make one larger so these values represent the edge of the data pixels.
y = np.arange(0, 290.5)

x = np.arange(0, 20.5)

pcm = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, Z, rasterized=True) # you don't need rasterized=True
fig.colorbar(pcm)
plt.xticks(np.arange(w), list('PNIYLKCVFWABCDEFGHIJ'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: What if values list is not randomly generated, they are from file input. values=read from a file, then reshaped into numpy array.

Comment: Forming your initial array is a different question, and its pretty hard to guess your use-case w/o understanding the format of your file...